# Camera renders blurry image in darker part of scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

I have a school project for which I need to make a small movie in Blender. All the animations are fine, but the moment my camera gets into the airduct I made, the preview gets all dark and blurry. I tried to set the FOV but it didn't work.
In the room before the camera works fine. I also added quite a handful of lights so I don't think it might be the problem.

Anyway here is the render preview. There is a point light just above the cube.
[image: Render]

[image: FoV Fixed]

Comment: Using Cycles render engine? Make sure there is enough light **in that part of the scene**. Also, add a screenshot/render of exactly what is happening when it gets to the airduct.

Comment: I am using cycles yes. I'll try to add more light but i wanted to created a bit dark/suspense atmosphere. Is it not possible ? Anyway i will post a screenshot when i have access to my pc (in around 3 hours 30)

Comment: It is possible, I'm just guessing that is why it is "blurry", without a screenshot I can't be sure.

Comment: I answered you in a new answer because stackexchange wont recognize me oncé im registered

Comment: Don't post an answer that isn't one! I am going to move the image to the question and then delete the answer post. When you are signed in you can edit your own posts. About the image, it looks like the camera focus is messed up. Check under your camera settings and see if the Depth of Field box has a focus object in it.

Comment: Ok. But why can't i comment then on my phone but not on my pc. It requires 50 reputation. It's annoying for me since i am logged in

Comment: You need to be signed into your original account, you appear to have made a duplicate one. You can always comment on your own posts.

Comment: Well seems like i am screwed sincd my mail adress used by this one is th same i used on the second one... and i have clicked on the link in tje mail. Anyway i added the fov fixed but its still bothering me a bit because i would like the background to not be blurry as well. Is it possible

Comment: I'm going to try and write an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your focus point for the camera is attatched to some other object in the scene, so that when you get into the air duct, it is all blurry. There are several ways to fix this, the best one is to add an empty (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Empty > Plain Axis*). Name it Camera Focus or something descriptive so you can find it easily later.

Now select the camera and go to *Camera Settings > Depth of Field* and select your empty.

[image: Add camera focus example]

You can now animate the position of the empty, and the camera will automatically focus on that point, so you can have it positioned near where you want to focus while it is still in the room, and then animate it to move into the air duct.

If your preview image is still pixelated like that, try rendering at a higher sample count.

Comment: Thanks i fixed it by deleting the few cameras i found with no use and changed dof to fstop and it worked :D